# Pass selected component to next step of form react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a multi step form, which is a quiz. I already set up the context to be able to pass  data.

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const QuizContext = createContext();

export default function QuizProvider({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const setQuizValues = (values) => {
    setData((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      ...values,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <QuizContext.Provider value={{ data, setQuizValues }}>
      {children}
    </QuizContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useQuizData = () => useContext(QuizContext);
```

So, my first step is selecting a card.
[image]

The code below:

```
import { Card } from "../../stories/Card";
import { useQuizData } from "../../context/index"
import { useState } from "react";

const tacos = [
  {
    cathegory: 'Meat',
    imgURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560781290-7dc94c0f8f4f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3024&q=80'
  },
  {
    cathegory: 'Fish',
    imgURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510130387422-82bed34b37e9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80'
  },
  {
    cathegory: 'Veggi',
    imgURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572527129705-a6c197003d61?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80'
  },
]

export const TacoCathegories = ({quizStep, prevQuizStep, nextQuizStep}) => {
  // const { setQuizValues } = useQuizData();
  const [isSelected, setisSelected] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    setQuizValues(values);
    prevQuizStep();
    nextQuizStep();
  };

  return (
    <div className={quizStep === 0 ? 'block': 'hidden'}>
      <div className="text-center">
        <h2 className="text-3xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-600 sm:text-4xl">What is your favourite taco group?</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-24 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="mt space-y-12 lg:space-y-0 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-x-8">
          {tacos.map((taco, index) => (
            <Card 
            role="button"
            key={index}
            title={taco.cathegory}
            source={taco.imgURL}
            text={`image of ${taco.cathegory} `}
            selected={isSelected === index}
            onChange={() => setisSelected(index)}
            />
            
          ))}
        </div>
        {tacos[isSelected] && <p>{tacos[isSelected].cathegory}</p>}
        
        <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-8 sm:flex sm:justify-center lg:justify-center">
          <div className="rounded-md shadow">
            <a role="button" tabIndex={0}
              className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10 cursor-not-allowed"
            >
              Back
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
            <a
              onClick={nextQuizStep}
              className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
            >
              Next
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am able to get the category of selected card `tacos[isSelected].cathegory`. Depending on the category I need to render different content in Step 2 of my multistep form. Basically, if I choose Meat I will render cards with Meat Tacos, If I choose Fish - with Fish Tacos. For now second step is empty, because I couldn't figure out how to pass selected category to second step.

```
export const TacoTypes = ({quizStep, prevQuizStep, nextQuizStep}) => {
    return (
      <div className={quizStep === 1 ? 'block' : 'hidden'}>
        <div>
            <p>Taco Types are: all you find in the object</p>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-8 sm:flex sm:justify-center lg:justify-center">
          <div className="rounded-md shadow">
            <a role="button" tabIndex={0}
              onClick={prevQuizStep}
              className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
            >
              Back
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
            <a
              onClick={nextQuizStep}
              className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
            >
              Next
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

I am new to react, so any tipp would be helpful!
Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-euler-pny5n

Comment: can you please share your code in codesandbox??

Comment: Added the edit, but the structure pretty complex, not sure if it's helpful

Comment: let me check it please

Comment: here I did some changes [Code Sandbox Link for Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-gauss-b6y63?file=/pages/quiz.js) that how you want ??

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. However, it doesn't render second step conditionally based on chosen card. Basically if isSelected Card is meat, in second step it should render Taco Types: Al Pastor, Barbacoa, Chorizo. If the isSelected Card is Fish, it should render Taco Types Camaron, Salmon, Pulpo, etc. For now second step of the form is same, no matter what I choose

Comment: check now please [CodeSandbox Link for Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-gauss-b6y63?file=/components/TacoQuizCards/TacoTypes.jsx)

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my life! That is so complex, I would never have found a solution by myself! If you know any source where I can read more on what you've done, please share! :)

Comment: you are welcome :). Not any specific resource I did changes in code just. If you want to know where did I make those changes or How it's working. I will explain that

Comment: I saw you kind of passe cathegories to the next step and also made those 'part' of both components. I also saw, that you added state management in quiz.js - I was trying to do it over Context and failed. But I understand the logic behind it. What I don't get, is how types know about to which cathegory they belong. Is it through index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235776/discussion-between-muhammad-bilal-bangash-and-katharina-schreiber).